# Flask app serving GPT2 on Google Cloud Run not persisting downloaded files?

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, pytorch, google-cloud-run, gpt-2

I have a Flask app running on Google Cloud Run, which needs to download a large model (GPT-2 from huggingface). This takes a while to download, so I am trying to set up so that it only downloads on deployment and then just serves this up for subsequent visits. That is I have the following code in a script that is imported by my main flask app app.py:

```
import torch
# from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelWithLMHead
# Disable gradient calculation - Useful for inference
torch.set_grad_enabled(False)

# Check if gpu or cpu
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

# Load tokenizer and model
try:
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("./gpt2-xl")
    model = AutoModelWithLMHead.from_pretrained("./gpt2-xl")
except Exception as e:

    print('no model found! Downloading....')
    
    AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2').save_pretrained('./gpt2-xl')
    AutoModelWithLMHead.from_pretrained('gpt2').save_pretrained('./gpt2-xl')
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("./gpt2-xl")
    model = AutoModelWithLMHead.from_pretrained("./gpt2-xl")

model = model.to(device)
```

This basically tries to load the the downloaded model, and if that fails it downloads a new copy of the model. I have autoscaling set to a minimum of 1 which I thought would mean something would always be running and therefore the downloaded file would persist even after activity. But it keeps having to redownload the model which freezes up the app when some people try to use it. I am trying to recreate something like this app https://text-generator-gpt2-app-6q7gvhilqq-lz.a.run.app/ which does not appear to have the same load time issue . In the flask app itself I have the following:

```
@app.route('/')
@cross_origin()
def index():
    prompt = wp[random.randint(0, len(wp)-1)]
    res = generate(prompt, size=75)
    generated = res.split(prompt)[-1] + '\n \n...TO BE CONTINUED'
    #generated = prompt
    return flask.render_template('main.html', prompt = prompt, output = generated)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',
            debug=True,
            port=PORT)
```

But it seems to redownload the models every few hours...how can I avoid having the app re-downloading the models and the app freezing for those who want to try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data written to the filesystem does not persist when the container instance is stopped.

Cloud Run lifetime is the time between an HTTP Request and the HTTP response. Overlapped requests extend this lifetime. Once the final HTTP response is sent your container can be stopped.

Cloud Run instances can run on different hardware (clusters). One instance will not have the same temporary data as another instance. Instances can be moved. Your strategy of downloading a large file and saving it to the in-memory file system will not work consistently.

[Filesystem access](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#filesystem)

Also note that the file system is in-memory, which means you need to have additional memory to store files.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way around this? The example app I linked never seems to take longer than 15-20 seconds to load and it is using the same pretrained model as mine. I found this, https://medium.com/google-cloud/3-great-options-for-persistent-storage-with-cloud-run-f1581ee05164 - but this seems mainly to be for writing things from the app, not to access them for serving. Would writing something that regularly pings the cloud run app and therefore extends the lifetime work?

Comment: @LXandor - Why do you "want to get around this"? Use services for what they are designed for and respect their limitations. One workaround is to put the file in the container before deploying the container. No, you cannot ping your instance.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant - thanks!! :) I was hoping there was something easy I just overlooked. Guess I need to learn more about how containers work, I thought they just processed code and wouldn't deploy large files....thanks for saving me some time